# Python Read Specific Lines to Calc

Tags: python

I have a list with numbers where I make a certain calculation and works perfectly, the list is a text file "file.txt", in it I have values (one in each line). In each calculation / check I use two lines, there are many lines in it, an example follows.

"file.txt"

```
73649
38761
34948
47653
98746
59375
90251
83661
```

... more lines / numbers

In this case I would use line 1 and 2 for a first calculation, I would like it to be FALSE when it uses lines 2 and 3, in case of FALSE, use lines 3 and 4 until it is TRUE.

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a structure where your numbers are grouped 2 by 2, so as you can make calculation on each pair?

Comment: Yes!!! I will use lines 1 and 2, in case of FALSE, I will use lines 2 and 3, in case of FALSE, I will use 3 and 4, and so on, until I find a TRUE. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is possible in Python. What is your problem, exactly? Is it reading the numbers, or pairing them? Do you know Python's `zip` function? You need to show more of your work and more context in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

(it won't be very efficient for extremely large text files over hundreds of megabytes)

```
def calc(x, y):

    # do your calculation here



file = open("file.txt", "r")

list = file.readlines()

file.close()

item = 0

while item < len(list) - 1:

    if calc(list[item], list[item + 1]) == false:

        item += 1

# once you have found the lines that output false, you can do whatever you 
# want with them with list[item] and list[item + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this code should answer your question:

```
lst = [int(line) for line in open('bar.txt','r')]

for n in range(len(lst)-1):
    a, b = lst[n], lst[n+1]
    if calculation(a,b): break
else:
    a, b = None, None
```

When you leave the loop, (a,b) contains the pair for which the `calculation` function has returned True. If all calls to `calculation` have returned False, (a,b) is replaced by (None,None)

Alternatively, when your data is streamed or cannot be totally stored in memory, you may directly loop over the stream lines:

```
with open('bar.txt', 'r') as file:
    a = None
    for b in file:
        b = int(b)
        if a != None and calculation(a,b): break
        a = b
    else:
        a, b = None, None
```